# How can I extract email addresses from between '<' and '>'?

Tags: python, email, string-formatting, text-processing

I've got a list of emails and names from Outlook, semicolon delimited, like this:

```
fname lname <email>; fname2 lname2 <email2>; ... ; fnameN lnameN <emailN>
```

And I'd like to extract the emails and semicolon delimit them like this:

```
email1; email2; ... ; emailN
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: finally, a task for which regexps *would* be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Using regex:](http://xkcd.com/208/)

```
import re
# matches everything which is between < and > (excluding them)
ptrn = re.compile("<([^>]+)>")
# findall returns ['email','email2']. Join concats them.
print '; '.join(ptrn.findall("fname lname <email>; fname2 lname2 <email2>;"))
# email; email2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension:

```
em = "fname lname <email>; fname2 lname2 <email2>; fnameN lnameN <emailN>"
email_list = [entry.split()[-1][1:-1] for entry in em.split(';')]

# email_list:
# ['email', 'email2', 'emailN']
```

**Breakdown**:

```
for entry in em.split(';')
```

First it splits up the original string by the semi-colon.

```
entry.split()
```

Next it takes each entry, splits it again, this time by space.

```
entry.split()[-1]
```

Next it selects the last entry from the split, which is your email.

```
entry.split()[-1][1:-1]
```

This takes your email, which is in the form of "`<email@addr.com>`" and selects the string contained within the angle brackets ([1:-1] corresponds to select from the second character to second-to-last).

Comment: Nice, good to know there's another way of thinking of this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

variations on a given theme:

```
s = 'fname lname <email>; fname2 lname2 <email2>; ... ; fnameN lnameN <emailN>'

print [ s[i+1 : i+s[i:].find('>')] for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == '<' ]

# OR

gen = ( i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c in '<>' )
print [ s[a+1:gen.next()] for a in gen]
```